# Javascript, after if continues to else

Tags: javascript

For some reason after the if, it continues to else, except the ifs that take you to a different place, here is the code i have at the moment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whatname(button) {
        var post = prompt("Name?", "Visitor")
        if(post == "Nick"){
            alert("Hi Nick")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
        if(post == "Visitor"){
            alert("Welcome Visitor")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
        if(post == ""){
            alert("Please Enter Name")
        }
        if(post == null){
            alert("Closing")
        }
        if(post == "show me a secret"){
            window.location = "secret.html"
        }
        if(post == "Greg"){
            alert("Test")
        }
        if(post == "greg"){
            alert("Test 1")
        }
        else{
            alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
    }
</script>
```

After the if happens, it continues to else, like let say i click cancel (which would be null) it would say, "Closing" but than another pop up would come up and would say, "Welcome Null, Have Fun!" than it would take me somewhere else, im not sure whats wrong, if you can help, it would be nice.

Comment: use else if that will help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `else if` rather than `if`

```
if(condition 1) {
} else if(condition 2) {
} else {
}
```

What's happening now is that it is first checking if `post` is "Nick". *Regardless of whether or not it is*, it will move on to check if `post` is "Visitor". This is of course not what you want. You only want to perform the second test if the first one was found to be false.

As written, only the very last `if` statement has an `else`. You will get the "Welcome, have fun"-message whenever `post` is anything but `greg`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the else is only applying to your last if.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whatname(button) {
        var post = prompt("Name?", "Visitor")
        if(post == "Nick"){
            alert("Hi Nick")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
        else if(post == "Visitor"){
            alert("Welcome Visitor")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
        else if(post == ""){
            alert("Please Enter Name")
        }
        else if(post == null){
            alert("Closing")
        }
        else if(post == "show me a secret"){
            window.location = "secret.html"
        }
        else if(post == "Greg"){
            alert("Test")
        }
        else if(post == "greg"){
            alert("Test 1")
        }
        else{
            alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way it will only execute one of the blocks of code.

Or better, change to use a switch statement
http://jsfiddle.net/qsQvs/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function whatname(button) {
    var post = prompt("Name?", "Visitor");

    switch (post) {
    case "Nick":
        {
            alert("Hi Nick");
            window.location = "index.html";
            break;
        }
    case "Visitor":
        {
            alert("Welcome Visitor");
            window.location = "index.html";
            break;
        }
    case "":
        {
            alert("Please Enter Name");
            break;
        }
    case "show me a secret":
        {
            window.location = "secret.html";
            break;
        }
    case "Greg":
        {
            alert("Test");
            break;
        }
    case "greg":
        {
            alert("Test 1");
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!");
            window.location = "index.html";
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have 7 different conditional blocks and the `else` is only part of the last one. In this case, since what you really want is 1 conditional block with 8 branches, you should be using `else if` instead of `if` on the middle 6:

```
if(post == "Nick") {
   alert("Hi Nick")
   window.location = "index.html"
} else if(post == "Visitor") {
    alert("Welcome Visitor")
    window.location = "index.html"
}

    [...]

else {
    alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
```

Also, since you are comparing the same variable to a bunch of different things, I would prefer to see this written as a switch, but that is a matter of taste:

```
switch(post)
{
    case "nick":
        alert("Hi Nick")
        window.location = "index.html"
        break;

    [...]

    default:
        alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
        window.location = "index.html"
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case only ONE on the IFs must happen (or the else), the you must use `else if`. Right now, the else only applies to the "greg" IF.

```
if(post == "Nick"){
    alert("Hi Nick")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else if(post == "Visitor"){
    alert("Welcome Visitor")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else if(post == ""){
    alert("Please Enter Name")
}
else if(post == null){
    alert("Closing")
}
else if(post == "show me a secret"){
    window.location = "secret.html"
}
else if(post == "Greg"){
    alert("Test")
}
else if(post == "greg"){
    alert("Test 1")
}
else{
    alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
```

Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` currently only triggers if the very last `if` does *not*.  Whether or not any of the *other* `if`s trigger, it doesn't care.

If you know it should only be one of these that ever fires, put `else`s before each if:

```
if(post == "Nick"){
    alert("Hi Nick")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else if(post == "Visitor"){   //Now this will only be considered if the first failed
    alert("Welcome Visitor")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
```

That way, the final else will only be considered if **all** else failed

Answer (score 1):

An `else` block is tied only to its immediately-preceding `if`, which means that all of your other `if` blocks are **independent** of one another. Use `else if` to create several **mutually exclusive** options.

Note, however, that you won't find any mention of `else if` in the JavaScript (ECMAScript) spec. It's not its own *thing*. But each `else` [is associated with the nearest possible `if` that has no `else`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.5), which allows you to string multiple conditions together.

In other words, this:

```
if (post == "Nick") {
    alert("Hi Nick")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else if (post == "Visitor") {
    alert("Welcome Visitor")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else if (post == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Name")
}
else {
    alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
if (post == "Nick") {
    alert("Hi Nick")
    window.location = "index.html"
}
else {
    if (post == "Visitor") {
        alert("Welcome Visitor")
        window.location = "index.html"
    }
    else {
        if (post == ""){
            alert("Please Enter Name")
        }
        else {
            alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
            window.location = "index.html"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you made a small mistake  try this code:

```
function whatname(button) {
    var post = prompt("Name?", "Visitor")

    if(post == "Nick"){
        alert("Hi Nick")
        window.location = "index.html"
    }
    else if(post == "Visitor"){
        alert("Welcome Visitor")
        window.location = "index.html"
    }
    else if(post == ""){
        alert("Please Enter Name")
    }
    else if(post == null){
        alert("Closing")
    }
    else if(post == "show me a secret"){
        window.location = "secret.html"
    }
    else if(post == "Greg"){
        alert("Test")
    }
    else if(post == "greg"){
        alert("Test 1")
    }
    else{
        alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")
        window.location = "index.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it would be much better suited in a switch statement, this would increase maintainability dramatically.

```
 var post = prompt("Name?", "Visitor") 
 switch(post)
 {
 case "Nick":
        alert("Hi Nick")  
        window.location = "index.html";  
        break;
 case "Visitor":
        alert("Welcome Visitor")  
        window.location = "index.html";
        break;  
 case "":
        alert("Please Enter Name") ;
        break;
 case null:
        alert("Closing");  
        break; 
 case "show me a secret":
        window.location = "secret.html";  
        break;
 case "Greg":  
        alert("Test");  
        break;
 case "greg":
        alert("Test 1")  
        break;    
 default:
        alert("Welcome " + post + ", Have Fun!")  
        window.location = "index.html";    
 }
```